# Delete data from mysql database

Tags: c++

Iam trying to delete data from my sql database using cpp.
Int id;
String query="DELETE FROM test WHERE id=id";
I think the variable id was not accessing in the query. What change i need to done here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your question to improve them, for example by showing us a [mcve] of your attempt, together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: You may want to look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-2.html

Answer (score 0):

you are passing a string after the equal not the real variable. maybe you should try type the query and concatenate the variable with the string after the double quotes so it will be like this

query = "DELETE FROM test WHERE id=" + id;